# JMS Header not getting stored into Spring Integration message header

Tags: spring-integration

Have an incoming message from ActiveMQ queue and the message is being delivered properly. I need to access the JMS header value `x-cutoffrule` in my spring integration flow, but the value of `cutoffrule` in the handle section always is coming as null. My code is below:

```
@Bean
public JmsHeaderMapper sampleJmsHeaderMapper() {
    return new DefaultJmsHeaderMapper() {
        public Map<String, Object> toHeaders(javax.jms.Message jmsMessage) {
            Map<String, Object> headers = super.toHeaders(jmsMessage);
            try {
                headers.put("cutoffrule", jmsMessage.getStringProperty("x-cutoffrule"));
            } catch (JMSException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return headers;
        }
    };
}


@Bean
public IntegrationFlow jmsMessageDrivenFlow(JmsHeaderMapper sampleJmsHeaderMapper ) {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(
                    Jms.messageDriverChannelAdapter(jmsMessagingTemplate.getConnectionFactory())
                            .destination(integrationProps.getIncomingRequestQueue())
                            .errorChannel(errorChannel())
                            .setHeaderMapper( sampleJmsHeaderMapper )
            )
            .handle((payload, headers) -> {
                incomingPayload = payload;
                logger.debug("cutoffrule"+ headers.get("cutoffrule"));
                return payload;
            })
            .handle(message -> {
                logger.debug("Message was succcessfully processed");
            })
            .get();
}
```

I thought the `DefaultJmsHeaderMapper` will map all JMS headers into the spring integration message. What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you use `sampleJmsHeaderMapper`? Why don't use "x-cutoffrule" inside your `(payload, headers) -> {...}` handler?

Comment: thats how i started by putting it directly in the handle(payload, headers), but I wasn't getting the values. So, moved to make it explicit by using DefaultJmsHeaderMapper with this implementation. Still doesn't work.

Comment: I wonder if your message really has that `x-cutoffrule` property... Please, debug your for confirmation. When we found the property, you will be able to map it into the appropriate header from your custom `toHeaders()`

Comment: I would try to remove `JmsHeaderMapper`, extract your handler as a separate class as a successor of `AbstractMessageProcessingTransformer` and change call from `handle` to `transform` in your chain. And in your successed `transform` method check presents of your field in `Message<?> message` parameter.

Comment: @StartingDev as you can see in my prev. comment `message` param has `org.springframework.messaging.Message` type with `getPayload` and `getHeaders` methods.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to understand what's wrong it to *debug* the code.
Or, at least *log* everything. 
The best place for you is that your `DefaultJmsHeaderMapper` extension.

So, the `DefaultJmsHeaderMapper` maps all incoming `properties`. But it does that with the `getObjectProperty()` not `getStringProperty()`, like in your code:

```
Enumeration<?> jmsPropertyNames = jmsMessage.getPropertyNames();
if (jmsPropertyNames != null) {
    while (jmsPropertyNames.hasMoreElements()) {
        String propertyName = jmsPropertyNames.nextElement().toString();
        try {
            String headerName = this.toHeaderName(propertyName);
            headers.put(headerName, jmsMessage.getObjectProperty(propertyName));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            if (logger.isWarnEnabled()) {
                logger.warn("error occurred while mapping JMS property '"
                            + propertyName + "' to Message header", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, your `x-cutoffrule` should be mapped exactly into the `x-cutoffrule` header.

See Andriy's comment, too.